# why JavaScript is behaving differently

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, performance, lua

why it is showing me 36 even though the minimum number is 27

```
   var combination = [27, 36]
    
    for (let x in combination) {
        if (combination[x] < 50) {
            var min = Math.min(combination[x])
        }
    }
    
    console.log(min)
```

i tried this multiple ways like

```
    var combination = [27, 30, 40, 44, 3, 239, 329, 2, 5, 20923, 96]
    
    for (let x in combination) {
        if (combination[x] < 50) {
            var min = Math.min(combination[x])
        }
    }
    
    console.log(min) //output--  5         //it should be 2
```

in this third example i add (-) to 2

```
var combination = [27, 30, 40, 44, 3, 239, 329, -2, 5, 20923, 96]

for (let x in combination) {
    if (combination[x] < 50) {
        var min = Math.min(combination[x])
    }
}

console.log(min) // output-- still 5     // it should be -2
```

again when am adding (-) to other numbers like in -96 or -5 the output was okay (-96) but when im adding (-) to 2 it is not showing me -2 in the output instead it showing me 5

not only in javascript i tried this with lua, php but output was same as js

can anyone explain me why this happen and how solve this

Comment: here since you are looping it replaces the smallest that is less than 50

Comment: also you are checking Math.min with just 1 number which makes no sense

Comment: What is the smallest number in this list: `36`?

Comment: you could try filtering out less than 50 numbers then apply Math.min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not comparing values to determine the minimum, but instead just replacing the `min` variable with the last number in the array that is smaller than `50`. This can be fixed as follows:

```js
let min = undefined;
for (let x in combination) {
    if (combination[x] < 50) {
        min = min == undefined ? combination[x] : Math.min(min, combination[x])
    }
}
```

Using `filter` and `reduce`, this can be made a lot shorter:

```js
combination.filter(x => x < 50).reduce((x, y) => Math.min(x, y))
```

Comment: what is that .reduce() method is doing??

Comment: @Noob: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for docs. Basically it always combines two values until only a single value remains using the provided function, thus "reducing" the array.